# C++ Pointer not updating the value

Tags: c++, pointers

```
//Inside the header.h

class telefonbok{
    std::map<std::string,std::string> telebok;
    std::map<std::string,std::string> aliasbok;
}
```

---

```
//Inside the cpp file
void telefonbok::alias(string name, string alias){
if (telebok.find(name) == telebok.end()) {

    cout << "Not found" << endl;

} else {

    //pointer = Adress stored in pointer.
    //*pointer = Value of *pointer

    string *pointer;
    pointer = &telebok.find(name)->second;
    aliasbok.insert(make_pair(alias, *pointer));
    cout << *pointer << endl;

}
```

When i change the value in the first map(telebok) the second value in the map(aliasbok) stays the same (the one who is supposed to have the pointer as the value).

Example:
add peter 123
lookup peter:
peter : 123
alias peter pete
lookup pete:
pete : 123
change peter 987
lookup peter:
peter : 987
lookup pete:
pete : 123

(Pete never changes wich is the issue, it's supposed to always have the same value as peter)

Comment: `alisasbok` doesn't save a pointer tough...

Comment: its because `telbok` and `aliasbok` both store their own copy of the string

Comment: You mean like std::map<std::string,std::"pointer"> aliasbok; or something?

Comment: i think @Florian meant that you use `std::map<std::string, std::string&> aliasbok` so you do not need to change much code

Comment: If you want to store pointers, you need a map with pointers as values: `std::map<std::string,std::string*> aliasbok;`

Comment: @Zaiborg STL maps cannot hold references as values ...

Comment: @dhke thanks for pointing that out, so as molbdnilo said, `std::string*` it is

Comment: Yeah i changed it to std::string* now but then another issue appears

Comment: aliasbok.insert(make_pair(alias, *pointer));   I can't have the * before the pointer, gives me error. If i write only pointer then i get the adress wich i dont want

Comment: @Widdin The pointer *is* an address. You can't have one but not the other.

Comment: We want the value of the adress wich is *pointer

Comment: Telebok[Peter, 123]          // aliasbok[Pete, <Points at telebok 123>]

Comment: Anyone can provide with help?, Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your code is inefficient (you call find twice, which is pretty expensive operation), so you should work with iterators, not pointers and it also will help to resolve your issue:

```
class telefonbok{
    typedef std::map<std::string,std::string> Telebok;
    typedef std::map<std::string,Telebok::const_iterator> Aliasbok;

    Telebok telebok;
    Aliasbok aliasbok;
};

void telefonbok::alias(string name, string alias)
{
    Telebok::const_iterator f = telebok.find( name );
    if( f == telebok.end() ) 
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
    else
        aliasbok.insert( make_pair( alias, f );
}
```

now you have following:

- you do not call `std::map::find()` twice
- through alias you can not only find number but original name as well

to print values from alias code little bit more complicated:

```
   for( Aliasbok::const_iterator it = aliasbok.begin(); it != aliasbok.end(); ++it )
       cout << "alias " << it->first << " has number " << it->second->second << " original name " << it->second->first << endl;
```

or to find a value:

```
  Aliasbok::const_iterator it = aliasbok.find( "abcd" );
  if( it != aliasbok.end() )
      cout << "phone for " << it->first << " is " << it->second->second << endl;
  else
      cout << "phone for abcd not found" << endl;
```

but you should get used to it when using iterators

Note: if you delete records from phonebook you need to clean aliasbook first, otherwise it will hold invalid iterators. Proper solution would be to use `boost::multi_index` but that probably too complicated for your level.

Comment: Is it possible to make an alias on an alias somehow?

Comment: Yes of course you can do that same way, but looks like you need to rework you design based on what requirements you have.

Comment: Btw, On "to print values from alias code little bit more complicated:"-code, How do i pint one specific value from the alias? I don't want all of them when i search for 1.

Comment: Code example shows how to print data based on iterator, only difference you get it as result of `find()` or `lower_bound()` instead of `begin()` rest is the same

Comment: Sorry i don't get it correctly, How is it supposed to be? `for (Aliasbok::const_iterator it = aliasbok.find(name); it != aliasbok.end();)`

Comment: And the alias on an alias, is that hard to do? Consider also if i make change number on the 3rd alias =>  then the regular name also changes

Comment: If you want to change number through alias change value type to `iterator` instead of `const_iterator`, 3rd level would work similar

Comment: How would my change function work then? `else if(aliasbok.find(name) != aliasbok.end()) { //Checks if the name exists in the map.
    aliasbok[name] = newnum; //If it exists, then replace the current number with newnum on the chosen name.
    cout << "Number was sucessfully changed.\n" << endl;`

Comment: Guess it's not "connected" to each other if i do like this.

Comment: you try to use wrong approach again, you use result of `find()` just to compare with `end()` but you should use iterator returned by find to change data if it does not point to `end()`, learn iterators in textbook

Comment: Are you familiar with saving to and loading from a txt.file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store shared pointers and set them apropriatelly to the same string.

```
class telefonbok{
std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<std::string>> telebok;
std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<std::string>> aliasbok;
}
```

and provide the methods to update the pointers as needed e.g.

```
void addphone(std::string const & name, 
   std::string const & alias, 
   std::string const & phone);
{
  std::shared_ptr<std::string> phone_ptr(new std::string(phone));
  telefonbok.telebok.emplace(name,phone_ptr);
  telefonbok.aliasbok.emplace(alias,phone_ptr);
}
```

and this way when you modify the phone on either it will get updated on both. Your phone will also not die when you exit the scope of the function.

Then you can do this for updates

```
void update_phone(std::string const & name, 
                  std::string const & newphone)
{
  if( auto iter = telefonbok.telebok.find(name) )
  {
     *(iter->second.get()) = newphone;
  } else if ( auto iter = telefonbok.aliasbok.find(name) )
  { 
      *(iter->second.get()) = newphone;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When i change the value in the first map(telebok) the second value in the map(aliasbok) stays the same (the one who is **supposed to have the pointer as the value**).

If the `aliasbok` is supposed to have pointer as the value, then your bug is that you've defined the map incorrectly. Here is your definition:

```
std::map<std::string,std::string> aliasbok;
```

Pay attention to how the value type of the map is `std::string` which is a value type and not `std::string*` which would be a pointer type.

Also pay attention to this line:

```
aliasbok.insert(make_pair(alias, *pointer));
```

Where you dereference the pointer and copy the pointed string into the pair, instead of copying a pointer.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but i have no clue how to fix it by myself. Atm i have `std::map<std::string,std::string*> aliasbok;` and changed to `aliasbok.insert(make_pair(alias, pointer));` but that only gives me an adress as value.

Comment: @Widdin sounds like you did correctly. The value of a pointer is the address of the pointed object.

Comment: But when i want to "lookup" on pete it gives me : 0038C964, Instead of the number. But if i change the in the insert to *pointer it gives me an error.

Comment: When you lookup a pointer from the map, what you get is the pointer. To get an object that is pointed to, you need to dereference the pointer. If you try to insert a string to a map of pointers, you'll of course get an error.

Comment: So how do i get the value because that's what i need? First time using pointers, sorry

Comment: I already told you. You can get the value by dereferencing the pointer. And you get the pointer by looking up the map.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what you mean with "dereferencing the pointer"

Comment: @Widdin that's what the dereference operator does.